# Column creation on Dataframe with expression variant

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to create a weighted average column on a DataFrame with this expression:

```
wa = pd.Dataframe()
i = 0

for i in range(10,0,-1):
  wa[0][i] = 1/(2**i)
```

I need a DataFrame like this:

```
wa = Index:[1/(2**10),1/(2**9),1/(2**8)...1/(2**0)]
```

Comment: Sorry but you have syntax errors in your code and it's hard to guess what you actually want, please edit the question in order to be solved

Comment: sorry for that, I’ve already changed this question several times, but I don’t understand how I can ask it directly, I need to generate a column from an exponential equation

Comment: I have answered the question according to what I think you need, just one more thing, there is line `print(round(x,5))` with `x` undefined, I guess it is here by accident, if not please explain this line further/add more code

Comment: yes, was an accident and you helped a lot ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n = 10
out = [1/2**i for i, i in zip(range(n,0,-1), range(n,0,-1))]
print(out)
```

Output is here:

```
[0.0009765625, 0.001953125, 0.00390625, 0.0078125, 0.015625, 0.03125, 0.0625, 0.125, 0.25, 0.5]
```

Then you can convert list to DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(out)
print(df)
```

The final dataframe looks like this:

```
          0
0  0.000977
1  0.001953
2  0.003906
3  0.007812
4  0.015625
5  0.031250
6  0.062500
7  0.125000
8  0.250000
9  0.500000
```